# How to represent an array of mixed-types in OpenAPI3?

Tags: yaml, swagger, postman, openapi, swagger-2.0

I have this array of items:

```
[ 
   1590340491.05, 
   95, 
   [1, 0, -0.01, 0.09, 0.98, 0.17, 0.01, 0, 0.98, 0.17, 0.02, 0, 1, 0, 0.04, -0.08, 0.98, 0.17, -0.05, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
   [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
   ["9-1-2-1"] 
]
```

I'm struggling to present this as an example in OpenApi3 in Swagger using YAML.
I've tried:

```
GraphData:
  type: array
  items:
    anyOf:
      - type: number
      - type: array
        items:
          type: number
      - type: array
        items:
          type: string
  minItems: 5
  example: [ 1590340491.05, 95, [1, 0, -0.01, 0.09, 0.98, 0.17, 0.01, 0, 0.98, 0.17, 0.02, 0, 1, 0, 0.04, -0.08, 0.98, 0.17, -0.05, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], ["9-1-2-1"] ]
```

But it ends up displaying this:

```
[
    75963062.21066117,
    -63391615.15094785,
    -10375297.783109933,
    45431809.68164119,
    13144786.222638994
]
```

Comment: Your API definition looks correct. What tool is producing incorrect result? I.e. when you say "it ends up displaying this" what is "it"?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I'm using Postman to translate this YAML script into API documentation